# What's the technical term for a "smart" installer?

Tags: windows-installer, installation

An example of what I mean is a small .exe installer (only a few hundred kb) that finds, downloads, and installs the latest version of your application.  This differs from a normal .exe installer where the program files are contained within the .exe installer package and the .exe version that you download is what gets installed (until updates are run within the program).

I'm trying to find a guide that covers making one, but can't find any due to lack of knowing the technical terms.  Anything "smart installer" related just returns search results about the "Smart Install" program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an *[online installer](https://www.google.com/search?q="online+installer"&oq="online+installer")*. It is considered polite to offer an offline installer too, for use on computers not connected to the internet.

Comment: Ahhh thanks!  Would you happen to know of any tutorials that go through creating one?

Comment: Search for [create "online installer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+"online+installer").